# How can I trigger final form onSubmit?

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, forms, react-final-form

I have a problem with React Final Form. I tried to follow the example on the official documentation, but I still don't understand why my form doesn't want to call the onSubmit as the example, and I'm still trying to understand what the role of handlesubmit is.

I think that the problem is that my fields are called from another component that uses the useField hook.

```js
import React, { FC } from 'react'
import { Form, Field } from 'react-final-form'
import {
  Grid,
  Box,
  Button,
  createStyles,
  makeStyles,
  Theme,
} from '@material-ui/core'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import InputField from './InputField'

interface InputFinalFormModalProps {
  fieldsValue: { title: string; value: string }[]
}

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    annullaBtn: {
      backgroundColor: '#fff',
      border: `1px solid ${theme.palette.secondary.main}`,
      color: theme.palette.secondary.main,
      fontFamily: 'HouschkaHead',
      fontSize: '17px',
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      paddingLeft: '40px',
      paddingRight: '40px',
      marginRight: '15px',
    },
    salvaBtn: {
      fontFamily: 'HouschkaHead',
      fontSize: '17px',
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      paddingLeft: '40px',
      paddingRight: '40px',
      marginLeft: '15px',
    },
    row: {
      width: '100%',
      textAlign: 'end',
    },
    container: {
      '& > .MuiGrid-item': {
        paddingBottom: '20px',
        paddingTop: '0px',
        paddingLeft: '11px',
        paddingRight: '11px',
      },
    },
  })
)

const sleep = (ms: number) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms))

const onSubmit = async (values: {}) => {
  await sleep(300)
  console.log(JSON.stringify(values))
}

const validate = (values: {}) => {
  const errors = {message: ''}
   if (!Object.values(values).toString()) {
         errors.message = "Required";
       }  

  return errors
}

const InputFinalFormModal: FC<InputFinalFormModalProps> = ({ fieldsValue }) => {
  const classes = useStyles()
  return (
    <Form
      onSubmit={onSubmit}
      validate={validate}
      render={({ handleSubmit, form, submitting, pristine, values }) => (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <Grid container className={classes.container}>
            {fieldsValue.map((field) => {
              return (
                <InputField title={field.title} value={field.value} />
              )
            })}
            
          </Grid>
          <Box className={classes.row} mt="20px">
            <Button className={classes.annullaBtn}>Annulla</Button>
            <Button
              type="submit"
              onClick={() => onSubmit(values)}
              className={classes.salvaBtn}
              disabled={submitting || pristine}
            >
              Salva
            </Button>
          </Box>
          {/* <button
            type="submit"
            onClick={() => onSubmit(values)}
            disabled={submitting || pristine}
          >
            Submit
          </button>
          <button
            type="button"
            onClick={form.reset}
            disabled={submitting || pristine}
          >
            Reset
          </button> 
          <pre>{JSON.stringify(values)}</pre>*/}
        </form>
      )}
    />
  )
}

InputFinalFormModal.displayName = 'InputFinalFormModal'

export default InputFinalFormModal
```

And here my snippet about the inputField

```js
import React, { FC, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useField } from 'react-final-form'
import {
  Box,
  Grid,
  createStyles,
  makeStyles,
  Theme,
  withStyles,
} from '@material-ui/core'
import InputLabel from '@material-ui/core/InputLabel'
import InputBase from '@material-ui/core/InputBase'
import { parse } from 'path'

interface InputFieldProps {
  title: string
  value: string
}


const BootstrapInput = withStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    input: {
      borderRadius: 4,
      position: 'relative',
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.common.white,
      border: '1px solid #bdc7d3',
      width: '100%',
      padding: '10px 12px',
      transition: theme.transitions.create(['border-color', 'box-shadow']),
      // Use the system font instead of the default Roboto font.
      fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
      fontSize: '14px',
      lineHeight: '1.21',
      fontWeight: 'normal',
      color: theme.palette.text.primary,
      '&:focus': {
        boxShadow: 'inset 0 0 12px 4px rgba(0, 179, 152, 0.05)',
        borderColor: theme.palette.secondary.main,
      },
    },
  })
)(InputBase)

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    inputTitle: {
      color: '#7C92A8',
      fontSize: '19px',
      lineHeight: 1.76,
      transition: 'font-weight 0.5s, color 0.5s',
      '&.Mui-focused': {
        color: theme.palette.secondary.main,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
      },
    },
    requiredText:{
      color: 'red'
    }
  })
)

const InputField: FC<InputFieldProps> = ({ title, value}) => {
  let {input, meta} = useField(title)
  const classes = useStyles()
  let [handleValidate, setHandleVlidate] = useState(false)
  let [required, setRequired] = useState('')

  useEffect(() => {
   if(parseInt(value)){
     setRequired('valore non valido')
     setHandleVlidate(true)
     /* if(isNaN(input.value)){
     } */
   }else{

     if(!input.value){
       setRequired('Campo Obbligatorio')
       setHandleVlidate(true)  
     }
   }
  },[input.value])


  return (
    <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
      <InputLabel
        shrink
        htmlFor="bootstrap-input"
        className={classes.inputTitle}
      >
        {title}
      </InputLabel>
      <BootstrapInput
        {...input}
        defaultValue={value}
        id="bootstrap-input"
        placeholder={value}
      />
       {meta.touched && !input.value && (
<span className={classes.requiredText}>{required}</span>
      )}
    </Grid>
    /*    <Grid item xs={6} lg={6}>
      <Box>
        <label className={classes.inputTitle} onClick={() => console.log('check')}>{title}</label>
      </Box>
      <input {...field.input} className={classes.inputField} placeholder={value} />
      {field.meta.touched && field.meta.error && (
        <span>{field.meta.error}</span>
      )}
        </Grid> */
  )
}

InputField.displayName = 'InputField'

export default InputField
```

Comment: did you tried putting a console.log('hitting on submit') on your submit function

Comment: yes, how you can see i tried to print the object that the onSubmit takes back from the form, but onothing. If i call it with an onClick inside the button, function works

Comment: so dealing with forms you can have multiple approaches, if you have multiple fields instead of handling onChange to each field will be using a single form tag which wraps all the fields since event delegation in js is there it will bubble up and each event target value we will get it. you can read more on this

Comment: so wait, what i have to do ? i still don't understand why it doesnt work

Comment: onSubmit function do a e.preventDefault() pass the event from the function where you bind it

Comment: wait, the preventDefault is not handled by the "submitting"? i mean, the disabled of the button depends to it. how the onSubmit function takes the preventDefault? i know that i call iit from the Form, so what do you mean with "pass the event from the function where you bind it?. I want to ask sorry if i don't get this =/ and thanks for your help!

Comment: can you try to create a working codesandbox with minimal reproducable issue so will be able to help you, sorry i got less time thats why

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-dew-5mue6

Comment: Error in codesandbox

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-dew-5mue6 it works for me now, i can see the entire form

Comment: you are not using Field Component from the package in the official docs they are using that one, did you tried with that one and checked it, even though you are customizing you need to use that Field component its basically for tracking and triggering

Comment: i'm using th ehooks useField in the InputField component

Answer (score 2):

If your form is valid, the validation function needs to return `{}`, not `{ message: '' }`.

Comment: without message: '' in works, thanks, now i will have to understand how to handle the validation errors to every field